# Mongoose Aggregate Over Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have record like this one:

```
  {
    created: "2017-01-01",
    values:{
     "0" : {
            "1":"9.9",
            "2":"10.9"    
      },
     "1" : {
            "1":"19.9",
            "2":"15.9"

      },
     ...
    }
  }
```

Suppose I would compute the means of values Object.
How can I do it with Mongo or Mongoose aggregation function?

Comment: Two issues I can see with this; first is the schema design is not suitable for doing aggregate operations using the aggregation framework as you have dynamic keys. The only approach is to change the `values` key to hold array values. The other issue is that your values are not numerical hence aggregate pipeline operators like `$avg` will not work on string values.

Comment: I canìt change the schema: this is (in my opinion) the best way to store IoT values for every minute in an hour. However, you are right: I changed the stored values.